# Formal method to predict borders for k-medoid clustering

Tags: k-medoids, voronoi

I've got a simple (two variable) data set that resolved nicely with k-medoids clustering (PAM) into three clusters. However, for presentation, I'd like to plot the points along with a Voronoi-style diagram, with estimated borders for the clusters. The borders would, of course, lie outside the convex hulls of each cluster. Is there a formal way to do this?

Comment: A Voronoi diagram will be drawn the same way whether you define the cluster centers as centroids, medioids, or anything else. Are you asking for software to plot a Voronoi diagram from the cluster centers, or the mathematical formula defining the boundaries, which are the line segments equidistant from pairs of centers?

Comment: Either will do, either an R routine or just the math.